# GraphViz - adding node to existing cluster

Tags: perl, graphviz

I'm using the Perl [`GraphViz`](https://metacpan.org/module/GraphViz) module to create a dependency tree graph. Say I have two classes, class A and class B. I would like all nodes in class A to be one cluster and all nodes in class B to be another cluster.

In Perl, I get the class of each node and do something along the lines of:

```
if ($currentClass ne $lastClass) {
    $classCluster = {name => "class B"};
}
else {
    $classCluster = {name => "class A"};
}

$graph->add_node($currentNode, cluster => $classCluster);
```

However, this doesn't seem to create the desired result. It creates a graph where all the nodes are graphing correctly, but instead of them being assigned to a proper cluster, they appear as though they are not part of any cluster. Also, "class A" and "class B" also appear in the graph, but there are no nodes inside them.

In other words, I'm trying to dynamically assign a node to a cluster. Any ideas how I can accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: @stevenl: This code is a very long way off working under `GraphViz2`, and I am sure it must be using `GraphViz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the `GraphViz` module, but I suspect that the problem is you are creating multiple anonymous hashes to define the same clusters.

Each time Perl executes `{name => "class B"}` it creates a *new* hash, so you are creating a new cluster for each node that just happens to have the same name.

I suggest you try writing

```
my $clusterA = { name => 'Class A' };
my $clusterB = { name => 'Class B' };
```

outside the main loop, and then replace the code you showed with

```
if ($currentClass ne $lastClass) {
    $cluster = $clusterB;
}
else {
    $cluster = $clusterA;
}

$graph->add_node($currentNode, cluster => $cluster);
```

and you should get some better results.

I am concerned about the way you are choosing between Cluster A and Cluster B. The way you have it, everything will go into Cluster A unless its class is different from the class of the previous node, and that doesn't seem right. But I can't tell properly without seeing more of your program, in particular the nature of your data and the loop that is adding nodes to the graph.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the fact that Perl creates a new hash every time. I ended up finding all the possible classes outside the loop and storing them in a hash.